# Redirect to page if data is missing

Tags: php, mysql

OK so I have been working far too long today and I am stuck on something simple (I think)

```
function commonData($uid)
{
    if ($uid)
    {
            $sql = "
                    SELECT a.user_id, a.email, a.username, a.displayname, a.level_id, a.photo_id
                    FROM engine4_users AS a
                    WHERE a.user_id = ".$uid;
    }

    $UserInfo = @mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql));

    if ($UserInfo[user_id])
    {

            if ($UserInfo[photo_id] && $UserInfo[photo_id]!="NULL")
            {
                    $PPhoto = @mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT a.* FROM engine4_storage_files AS a WHERE a.file_id = ".$UserInfo[photo_id]));
                    $photo = SITE.$PPhoto[storage_path];
            }
            else $photo = NO_PHOTO; 

    $queryMoreProfile = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM engine4_user_fields_values AS a WHERE a.item_id = ".$UserInfo[user_id]);

    while ($moreProfile = @mysql_fetch_assoc($queryMoreProfile))
    {

            //$location = '';
            if ($moreProfile['field_id']==24)
            {
                    $locationNumber = $moreProfile['value'];
                    $locationsql = @mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT a.* FROM engine4_user_fields_options AS a WHERE a.option_id = ".$locationNumber));

                    if (isset($locationsql['label']) && !empty($locationsql['label']))
                    {
                            $location = $locationsql['label'];
                    }
            }

            //if(empty($location))
            //{
            //      header("Location: http://www.fetishmen.net/members/edit/profile");
            //      exit;
            //}
}
```

What I am TRYING to do is say, IF `$location` has no value (missing out of the database completely) redirect to a page.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: OK so I posted the whole code for the function... yes I cut out some if statements that do not apply... I hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexes of the array `$moreProfile` and `$locationsql` need to be either a variable or a string,

```
if ($moreProfile['field_id']==24) //or $field_id
{
    $locationNumber = $moreProfile['value']; //or $value
    $locationsql = @mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT a.* FROM engine4_user_fields_options AS a WHERE a.option_id = ".$locationNumber));
    $location = $locationsql['label']; //or $label 
}

if(empty($location))
{
    header("Location: http://website.com");
    exit;
}
```

**Edit:** As per OP's comments,

```
  if ($moreProfile['field_id'] == 24 ) 
{
    $locationNumber = $moreProfile['value']; //or $value
    $locationsql = @mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT a.* FROM engine4_user_fields_options AS a WHERE a.option_id = ".$locationNumber));
    $location = $locationsql['label']; //or $label 
} else if(empty($moreProfile['field_id'])) {
     header("Location: http://website.com");
     exit;
}
```

Comment: This is where I should clarify what is above... 
        $queryMoreProfile = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM engine4_user_fields_values AS a WHERE a.item_id = ".$UserInfo[user_id]);


        while ($moreProfile = @mysql_fetch_assoc($queryMoreProfile))

Comment: I am sorry if I seem like a noob... I am just tired and confused and cant figure this out and get it out of my head

Comment: is `field_id` a column in table `engine4_user_fields_values` ?

Comment: yes it is... so basically it either will have in this case 24 as the 'field_id' or there will be no data to be found

Comment: so to clarify, it will first pull all the data for the user_id... then if the user ID has a field_id for 24 there will be a corresponding 'value' but if that field_id of 24 is missing, I need it to redirect them to a page to fix their profile

Comment: yep, put it in quotes, doesn't help the cause.  I am thinking it has to do with empty() ... will that work if there is no data in the database to be found?

Comment: Edited my answer as per your comments.

Comment: This is the right solution under most circumstances, however due to what is happening in the background this solution does not work (I am calling a swf file).  But this solution did help me come up with how to fix my problem by moving this to another file first.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop using @ and put in place proper checking that mysql_result and mysql_fetch_assoc is returning something. Try this and see if it redirects for you:

```
$location = '';

if ($moreProfile['field_id']==24)
{
    $locationNumber = $moreProfile['value'];
    $locationsql = @mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT a.* FROM engine4_user_fields_options AS a WHERE a.option_id = ".$locationNumber));

    if (isset($locationsql['label']) && !empty($locationsql['label'])) {
            $location = $locationsql['label'];
    }
}

if(empty($location))
{
    header("Location: http://website.com");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: no sorry didnt work... unfortunately I think this is a context thing... you really should see the whole file, but I know people here don't like that... I think I will take another 10 minutes to look at it then leave it for the night... I will check in the morning for more suggestions

Comment: "didnt work" doesn't help me here. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: so basically the error I am getting on the script is authentication failed.  This script is a common.handler for a series of auth types.  this part of the file is for pulling user profile information out for a chat site.  what you see is in a function under a where clause.  its wierd, cause if I remove the top $location line and I remove all the if(empty..... statement it works and if the user has their location set it shows up... what I am trying to do is forward people to an edit profile page if they do not have a country set.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Not sure what exactly the issue is. Perhaps it is that your code never gets to the if ($moreProfile['field_id']==24) line

Comment: it does get there because the data is populated